# Android push notification when app is killed

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

Push message is received well when app in background or foreground state.
When app is killed push never comes.

Push data:

```
{
 "to" : "e3UQwRr.....,
 "click_action" : "asd",
 "priority":"high",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "First Notification1",
     "title": "Collapsing A",
     "key_1" : "Data for key one",
     "key_2" : "Hellowww"
 }
}
```

Im testing is `Postman`, response contains: `"success": 1,"failure": 0`

To mention: when app is in foreground state i see my code parses the messages, when app is in background i see push is handled by the system.
So what could be the reason when app is killed notifications not come?

On some devices - LeEco Le2, battery optimization is off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Comment: also read here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/41#issuecomment-306066751

Comment: The reason is those devices use a Background execution strategy which restrict any background service from running. I ahave faced same problem in some devices even running on API21(Xioami). Well there is a AutoStart option in setting turn it on .

Comment: @GastónSaillén in accepted answer Antonio pointed to data message. As you can see i use it too.